# ZendF 2 form view helper escapes attributes

Tags: zend-framework2, view-helpers, zend-form2

i just started working with ZendF 2 and i noticed some wired behaviour when in Zend\Form. i tried to set 2 classes to the form instance using

```
$this->setAttribute('class', 'class1 class2');
```

then, in view i call

```
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form); ?>
```

the output is

```
<form class="class1&#x20;class2" id="login-form">
```

why is the space between class1 and class2 escaped? is this normal? as far as i tested it it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is normal.

```
&#x20;
```

is the HTML code for space. The browser interpreter will recognize it as a white space.

In fact if you try to put that code in a comment here it will be interpreted as a white space.